# Jsonp request refuses to work

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I got the following code:

```
var url = 'https://lottery.lafunda.com.do/Lottery/WinningNumbers?key=664cf843-8904-4212-9503-d4733651f519&gobackdays=2&grouped=true&language=es-DO&callback=generateTicker';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    accept: "application/javascript",
    dataType: "jsonp"
});



function generateTicker(returndata) {
  console.log(returndata);
}
```

But nothing happens. In the console Im getting this message: 
"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"

Here is JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8k8souqj/

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Most of you are pointing out the URL does not return valid json. But if I use a modify header extension for chrome and accept "application/javascript" as a header I do get valid javascript:

```
 generateTicker([{"HouseAbbreviation":"LIL","ClosesOn":"2014-10-15T02:10:00","HouseName":"Illinois Noche","Drawings":[{"HouseAbbreviation":"LIL","HouseName":"Illinois Noche","ClosesOn":"2014-10-15T02:10:00","BallCount":2,"PostedNumbers":"3-0"},{"HouseAbbreviation":"LIL","HouseName":"Illinois Noche","ClosesOn":"2014-10-15T02:10:00","BallCount":3,"PostedNumbers":"6-3-0"}... etc
```

**EDIT 2:**

Apparently the problem is that jsonp cannot use modified headers as this is not possible via the script tag. Hence the URL will always return html. Thanks to all

Comment: In your fiddle: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Um the url you are fetching is not returning JSONP. That is why it is not working.

Comment: If you assign the header to "application/javascript" the URL returns valid javascript. @epascarello

Comment: Not everyone will have this Chrome extension. The site will not work for any other user.

Comment: I think that your EDIT 2 is not really true, I think that you should set your Accept header as I described in the response, does this fiddle solve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/8k8souqj/13/

Answer (score 0):

That code fetches an HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Winning Numbers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/webordertaker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/select2.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="winningNumbersView">
  <div id="layoutContainer">



<h2>N&#250;meros Ganadores</h2>

<table class="table" id="winningNumbersTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Casa</th>
      <th>N&#250;meros</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>LIL Illinois Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>3-0</td>
              <td>6-3-0</td>
              <td>7-9-2-2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>NPR Puerto Rico Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>3-5</td>
              <td>4-3-5</td>
              <td>0-9-6-3</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>LFL Florida Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>4-1</td>
              <td>3-4-1</td>
              <td>9-9-7-6</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>LNJ Nueva Jersey Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>3-9</td>
              <td>1-3-9</td>
              <td>9-9-6-4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>LNY Nueva York Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>7-6</td>
              <td>8-7-6</td>
              <td>6-1-1-4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>LNYMAR Marriage NY Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>76-61-14</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>LNYBOR Borlette NY Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>76-61-14</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>DPR Puerto Rico D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>9-3</td>
              <td>5-9-3</td>
              <td>6-4-6-4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>EIL Illinois D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>9-6</td>
              <td>0-9-6</td>
              <td>1-4-4-4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>EFL Florida D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>5-2</td>
              <td>2-5-2</td>
              <td>3-9-2-3</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>ENJ Nueva Jersey D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>3-2</td>
              <td>1-3-2</td>
              <td>6-8-7-2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>ENYMAR Marriage NY D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>85-02-78</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>ENYBOR Borlette NY D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>85-02-78</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/10/14</td>
      <td>ENY Nueva York D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>8-5</td>
              <td>6-8-5</td>
              <td>0-2-7-8</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>LIL Illinois Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>2-8</td>
              <td>8-2-8</td>
              <td>0-1-3-4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>LFL Florida Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>6-5</td>
              <td>0-6-5</td>
              <td>5-0-8-2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>NPR Puerto Rico Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>5-6</td>
              <td>4-5-6</td>
              <td>9-4-1-0</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>LNJ Nueva Jersey Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>7-5</td>
              <td>4-7-5</td>
              <td>7-1-1-8</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>LNYMAR Marriage NY Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>71-62-44</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>LNYBOR Borlette NY Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>71-62-44</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>LNY Nueva York Noche</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>7-1</td>
              <td>2-7-1</td>
              <td>6-2-4-4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>DPR Puerto Rico D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>7-5</td>
              <td>0-7-5</td>
              <td>5-2-6-0</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>EIL Illinois D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>9-8</td>
              <td>0-9-8</td>
              <td>8-1-5-9</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>EFL Florida D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>5-5</td>
              <td>9-5-5</td>
              <td>2-6-6-8</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>ENJ Nueva Jersey D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>0-0</td>
              <td>5-0-0</td>
              <td>0-7-2-7</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>ENY Nueva York D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>8-4</td>
              <td>1-8-4</td>
              <td>3-2-9-9</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>ENYMAR Marriage NY D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>84-32-99</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13/10/14</td>
      <td>ENYBOR Borlette NY D&#237;a</td>
      <td>
        <table class="inner-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>84-32-99</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/iframeResizer.contentWindow.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

...but HTML is not valid JSONP.

Comment: If you assign the header to "application/javascript" it fetches valid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The callback will never work this way. You will have to add your callback to you ajax request.

```
var url = 'https://lottery.lafunda.com.do/Lottery/WinningNumbers?key=664cf843-8904-4212-9503-d4733651f519&gobackdays=2&grouped=true&language=es-DO&callback=generateTicker';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    accept: "application/javascript",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: generateTicker
});

function generateTicker(returndata) {
  console.log(returndata);
}
```

Comment: No, it gives errors in your console. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < `, meaning the received data is no json data.

Comment: Must be the way im trying to send the accept header request? I edited the original post showing I do get a json return.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the combination of the two errors, as Jerodev mention, the way you call callback method won't work, and also, what you mentioned the way you send the accept header is not proper either

The following should work

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/javascript"
    },
    url: url,
    data: "jsonp",
    success : generateTicker
})

function generateTicker(returndata) {
    console.log(returndata);
}
```

The working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8k8souqj/13/